# Asp.Net Web API oAuth 2.0 cannot validate with password containing ampersand (&)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, oauth, owin, jwt

I am having a wired issue in my AngularJs application. When user is trying to login to the app and if the password contains ampersand (&), then it couldn't able to validate the user.

I am using OWIN, oAuth2.0 JWT token to validate my Asp.Net Web APIs.

When i debug i found that if the password contains ampersand (&), then it is truncating all the characters from ampersand (&).

For example, if the password is 'x&x' the OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context is getting only 'x' in password value.

I have attached a screen shot of the issue [click to see the issue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/El5po.png).

Any help on this issue, would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Am guessing the value is being interpreted as a query string separator.

Try using the javascript method

```
encodeURI()
```

Or

```
EncodeURIcomponent()
```

On your password value before posting to the server, so the ampersand becomes

```
&amp;
```

The server will decode this for you.
You'll probably find that slashes and question marks will also not work in passwords if you dont

Comment: Since i am new and have less than15 reputation it is not letting me do that or am i missing something. Please let me know.

Comment: You click on the tick that appears when you move you mouse / touch the bit on the left hand side of my answer, between the upvote and downvote buttons :) You don't yet have enough reputation to vote on answers but you can accept answers to questions you ask :) Have a good day, glad I could help

Comment: I just clicked on the tick. Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you, hope your project is a success my friend

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with an anguar project while entering special characters(ex: &, +) in password field. Encoding password with encodeURIComponent did the trick:

"&password=" + encodeURIComponent(password)

Hope it helps