# Include ampersand '&' and '+' special characters in password as OAuth 2 request

Tags: rest, url, spring-security, passwords, form-data

Including special characters like **'&'** and **'+'** in password like **'password&123'** and **'password+123'** in my oauth2 request for token in login form **Form data** goes like

1. For 'password&123' it separates the url and takes 123 as param key since & is param separatar 123 in request url

http://localhost:4200/api/oauth/token

```
username=user1&password=password&123&grant_type=password&scope=read%20write%20trust&client_id=appset&client_secret
   =appset

Form data : Goes like
---------------------

username:user1
password:password          <-- password&123 since & param separatar 123     
123:                           changes to param key   
grant_type:password
scope:read write trust
client_id:appset
client_secret:appset
```

2. For password with + i.e 'password+123' + is replaced with space

http://localhost:4200/api/oauth/token

```
 username:user2
 password:password 123          <-- + is replaced with space
 grant_type:password
 scope:read write trust
 client_id:appset
 client_secret:appset

 username=user2&password=password+123&grant_type=password&scope=read%20write%20trust&client_id=appset&client_secret
 =appset
```

And getting obvious invalid credential.

How to include '&' and '+' as password in my request URL form data. Any help would be great.

Tried [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34729986/asp-net-web-api-oauth-2-0-cannot-validate-with-password-containing-ampersand) looked like same issue added **encodeURI()** it didn't help

Comment: Who is preparing the uri ? If it is you then you should encode each qeury param value before you send the request ..

Comment: As you have mentioned , rest, does that mean you try to get params in a method by using request.getParam("password") ???

Comment: you may try to pass the password using a form instead of within the url itself. this way, you pass the password as a string without constraints.

Comment: No we are using spring security oauth2 for /oauth/token authentication in spring-security and we define the db check where to find in standalone-full wildfly config

Comment: Using encodeURIComponent() yields better results, than just encodeURI() for these kind of special characters. It encodes them into %## - If you are desperate, you could always base64 encode/decode but I'd try fix the issue in the root cause, the API used to encode the URI params. :)

Comment: I ll try encodeURIComponent()

Comment: have you tried passing `password%26123` and `password%2B123` ? To url encode/decode  : take a look [here](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/)

Comment: @AlexPedersen form data goes like username=user1&password=password&123&grant_type=password&scope=read%20write%20trust&client_id=appset&client_secret=appset: it fails

Comment: I encrypted this.oAuth2RequestBody(userName, encodeURIComponent(password)) alone it works great @AlexPedersen encodeURI didnt work dont but encodeURIComponent works

Comment: But @AlexPedersen mentions special Using encodeURIComponent() yields better results, than just encodeURI() for these kind of special characters in this thread